# Change the color theme of the app in Vuex using the Store

Tags: vue.js, store, vuex

How to implement the transition between two color themes tied to a language change?

Languages are changed using the Vuex Store. It is necessary when changing the language to change the body class.

Story state:

```
export default {
  language: {
    current: { name: 'en'},
    available: [{ name: 'en' }, { name: 'ru' }]
  }
}
```

Story action:

```
export default { ['app:language:change']({ commit }, language) { 
 commit('app:language:change', language); },
}
```

Story mutation:

```
export default { ['app:language:change'](state, language) { 
 state.language.current = language; },
}
```

Component-language change

```
<tempalte v-for="(lang, index) in availableLanguages">
   <span style="cursor: pointer;"  v-on:click="() => 
     onLanguageChange(lang)">{{ lang.name }}</span>
   <span v-if="index !== availableLanguages.length - 1"> / </span>
</tempalte>

<script>
    export default {
      name: 'app-footer',
    computed: {
     language()
       {return this.$store.state.language.current;},
     availableLanguages() 
       {return this.$store.state.language.available;}
    },
    methods: {
      onLanguageChange(lang) {
        this.$store.dispatch('app:language:change', lang); }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Example of a component in which the language changes

```
<template>
    <h1> {{ language && title && title[language.name] }} </h1>
</template>
<script>
    const ABOUT_DIC = {
       title: {
         en: 'About',
         ru: 'Компания'
       }
     };
     export default {
        name: 'about',
        data () {
           return { title: ABOUT_DIC.title }
        },
        computed: {
            language() {
               return this.$store.state.language.current; }
     }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind class names dynamically in vue and as you appear to only have two options you could use a ternary expression to determine which class is bound. As you are already getting your language name from your store you could use that to determine the class. Something like this:

```
<template>
  <div v-bind:class="[language.name === 'en' ? englishClass : russianClass]">
    <h1> {{ language && title && title[language.name] }} </h1>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    const ABOUT_DIC = {
       title: {
         en: 'About',
         ru: 'Компания'
       }
     };
     export default {
        name: 'about',
        data () {
           return { 
             title: ABOUT_DIC.title, 
             englishClass: 'blue',
             russianClass: 'green'
             }
        },
        computed: {
            language() {
               return this.$store.state.language.current; }
     }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
  .blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .green {
    background-color: green;
  }
```

And obviously you can have any styling you want in the blue or green class. The vue.js docs on this are [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)